# Не создаётся репозиторий, наследующий CrudRepository. Spring Boot, Hibernate, PostgreSQL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Я пытаюсь создать своё первое веб-приложение на **Spring**, использую **Spring Boot** и **Hibernate** для работы с базой данных **PostgreSQL**.

Всё работало до того самого момента, когда я решил перейти на настоящую БД (до этого все данные хранились в ArrayList), тогда всё прекрасно работало.

Все необходимые зависимости в **pom.xml** я указал, делаю всё как в многочисленных видео туториалах, но на моменте создания интерфейса, который наследуется от CrudRepository я, видимо, что-то делаю не так.

Когда я пытаюсь запустить приложение, вылетает ошибка:
`Parameter 0 of constructor in com.springnova.springproj.auxclasses.dao.PersonDAO required a bean of type 'com.springnova.springproj.repos.PersonRepository' that could not be found.`

### Класс PersonDAO:

```
import com.springnova.springproj.auxclasses.models.Person;
import com.springnova.springproj.repos.PersonRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Optional;

@Component
public class PersonDAO {
    private final PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Autowired
    public PersonDAO(PersonRepository personRepository) {
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
    }

    public Iterable<Person> index() {
        return personRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Person show(Long id) {
        Optional<Person> res = personRepository.findById(id);
        if (res.isPresent()) {
            return res.orElse(new Person());
        }
        return null; //people.stream().filter(person -> person.getId() == id).findAny().orElse(null);
    }

    public void save(Person person) {
        personRepository.save(person);
    }

    public void update(Long id, Person updatedPerson) {
        Person toUpdate = show(id);
        toUpdate.setName(updatedPerson.getName());
        toUpdate.setAge(updatedPerson.getAge());
        toUpdate.setEmail(updatedPerson.getEmail());
    }

    public void delete(Long id) {
        Optional<Person> res = personRepository.findById(id);
        if (res.isPresent()) {
            personRepository.delete(personRepository.findById(id).orElse(new Person()));
        } //people.removeIf(p -> p.getId() == id);
    }
}
```

### Класс Person:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="people")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Имя не может быть пустым")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 30, message = "Имя должно быть длиной от 2 до 30 символов")
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Min(value = 0, message = "Возраст не может быть меньше нуля")
    @Column(name = "age")
    private int age;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Почта не может быть пустой")
    @Email(message = "Почта должна быть действительной")
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Person(int id, String name, int age, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Person() {

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

### Класс PeopleController:

```
import com.springnova.springproj.auxclasses.dao.PersonDAO;
import com.springnova.springproj.auxclasses.models.Person;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/people")
public class PeopleController {

    private final PersonDAO personDAO;

    @Autowired
    public PeopleController(PersonDAO personDAO) {
        this.personDAO = personDAO;
    }


    @GetMapping()
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("people", personDAO.index());

        return "people/index";
    }


    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public String show(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("person", personDAO.show(id));

        return "people/show";
    }


    @GetMapping("/new")
    public String newPerson(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person) {
        return "people/new";
    }


    @PostMapping()
    public String create(@ModelAttribute("person") @Valid Person person,
                         BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "people/new";
        }
        personDAO.save(person);

        return "redirect:/people";
    }


    @GetMapping("/{id}/edit")
    public String edit(Model model, @PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        model.addAttribute("person", personDAO.show(id));

        return "people/edit";
    }


    @PatchMapping("/{id}")
    public String update(@ModelAttribute("person") @Valid Person person,
                         BindingResult bindingResult,
                         @PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "/people/edit";
        }
        personDAO.update(id, person);

        return "redirect:/people";
    }


    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public String delete(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        personDAO.delete(id);

        return "redirect:/people";
    }

}
```

### Сам интерфейс PersonRepository:

```
import com.springnova.springproj.auxclasses.models.Person;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
}
```

Если нет бина типа **PersonRepository**, мне нужно его создать? Но где и как? В **PersonDAO** есть поле типа PersonRepository, которое **@Autowired** через конструктор, но ошибка всё равно вылетает.

Прилагаю ссылку на гитхаб моего проекта: **https://github.com/Saluro/wind-walk**

Answer (score 0):

Спустя целый день разбирательств, методом проб и ошибок, я обнаружил, что чтобы не вылетала такая ошибка, нужно в класс с аннотацией **@SpringBootApplication** добавить ещё одну аннотацию **@EnableJpaRepositories("путь к пакету с интерфейсами")**.

---

В моей структуре проекта это было **com.springnova.springproj.repos**
Внутри этого пакета и лежал интерфейс **PersonRepository**